# bash how to add new line and comment to the log file

Tags: bash, logging

I would like to automate deployment on development server.

```
/usr/bin/php artisan -n migrate:refresh >> /var/svn/project/hooks/artisan.log
/usr/bin/php artisan -n db:seed >> /var/svn/project/hooks/artisan.log
```

I'd like each new entry to start from newline.

And add comment such as

```
[migrate:refresh] ...
[db:seed] ...
```

at the beginning of each line corresponding to artisan command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear. I think you mean you want to prefix the output of artisan with a comment... if not, please clarify.

```
output=$(/usr/bin/php artisan -n migrate:refresh)
echo [migrate:refresh] $output >> artisan.log
```

Or maybe, just output your comment to the log, but without a newline, before running artisan.

```
echo -n [migrate:refresh] >> artisan.log
/usr/bin/php artisan -n migrate:refresh >> artisan.log
```

Or this one liner:

```
(echo -n [migrate:refresh]; /usr/bin/php artisan -n migrate:refresh) >> file
```

Or maybe you want to prefix every line:

```
/usr/bin/php artisan -n migrate:refresh | sed 's/^/\[migrate:refresh\]/' >> log
```

Comment: Yes! could there be a 1 liner? How about line break?